# Node.js HTTP proxy cache: any guidelines and best practices?

Tags: caching, node.js, proxy

Are there any guidelines/best practices to implement a cache in an http proxy written in node.js ? Is it better a fully memory loaded cache, a disk stored cache or a mixed one?

Any advice on this?

thanks

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote or select it.

Answer (score 1):

What are the reasons that you want a proxy cache? Are you trying to build one to learn more about caching principles? If so, then it'd be pretty easy to build one in Node.js. If you actually want one for performance, then I'd skip Node.js altogether for building a proxy cache and take a look at [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

If you insist on building one in Node.js, you'll want to leverage the work of [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and build an in-memory cache. YMMV, but you'll probably want to avoid a disk cache as that sort of defeats the purpose. [Redis](http://redis.io/) could be of some use for your memory cache.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: that's a good point to start! I need to add some caching functions to a custom node http proxy. I'll look a Varnish docs for some ideas and use Redis for memory cache. thank you. Any further suggestion is appreciate.